# Mage::getStoreConfig not returning updated values

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Recently we've noticed that Mage::getStoreConfig is not returning updated values in a app/code/local plugin. Everything was working as of last Friday so we assume that something has changed on the server.

We can see the values updating correctly in the database table core_config_data.

We have

- recompiled
- flushed the Magento Cache
- flushed the Cache Storage
- reset folder and file ownership and permissions

  find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

For example, we added an extra character to the store phone number, see that the database value has updated but it doesn't show with the following line

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone')
```

As a test we duplicated the site and database via Plesk and applied the latest patches to both sites. The duplicated site worked as normal.

I'm intrigued to find out what has happened so any ideas as to what the issue might be would be welcome?

Comment: Flush cache storage.

Comment: @DavidTay Thanks for the suggestion. I've already tried flushing Magento Cache & Cache Storage

Comment: @SeanDooley Are you using correct path value to fetch the values? Which type of value you are trying to fetch text or numeric?

Comment: @Muk Tested this with various value types (int, string, etc). Updated values aren't pulled through. Initial thoughts are issues with the cache and / or permissions.

Comment: @SeanDooley Are you using any other caching , other than Magento default?

Comment: @Muk No. Everything was working as normal. We duplicated the site to a staging area and everything worked correctly so I'm wondering what has changed

Comment: Where are you trying to get these values? Is it in Magento itself, or a script you're running? I ask because I had something similar happen: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61818/seemingly-wrong-information-from-magegetstoreconfig

Comment: @SeanDooley What do you mean by "updated values"? Are you getting default values returned? can you supply an example of the getStoreConfig command you're using?

Comment: If you are running multi-store, you may want to make sure store view or website isn't overriding you default value.

Comment: Not running a multi-store